# How to get list of added[Imported] files in SharpSVN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I'm trying to get a list of added files from SharpSVN .

I'm,using SharpSVN to import files to repository. 
  For this i am using the below line of code

```
client.Import(localPath, new Uri(targetURI), importArgs, out commitResults)
```

I am successfully importing. But i want to retrieve the file added to repository.

Can somebody point me to the right spot in the SharpSVN maze to replicate this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways to do this:

1. You can attach to the .Notify event (on either the `SvnClient` or the `SvnImportArgs` instance) and see what is committed, when it is committed.
2. You can attach to the .Committing event (on either the `SvnClient` or the `SvnImportArgs` instance) and see what is to be committed (and potentially tweak the log message)
3. Use `SvnClient.Log()` to obtain 'whatever is committed in revision X'.